# Is there a name for different sql Statement methods?

Tags: sql, methods, db2

I have take over a position as a BI consultant.  and almost ALL of the prior SQL are build in a very funny way.. Especially compared to what i have been teached..  And I wonder if the other "way" has particular name..  Some times when i try to explain how the old things are build, and why they are so complicated to change, compared to the way i'm building it where they are getting change pretty quickly..

I have always "learned" to make 1 script,  with CTE, DT, SUBQUERIES ETC..  But all of the previous code are build in many many steps.

Even simple tasks are build up in MANY steps..

For example if they wanted to find info from 3 different tables.  it could be like (simplyfied for example reasons, i have scripts i have rewritten from 56 steps, to 2 steps. and gotten 76% performance boost)

```
Create qtemp.cust as (  
Select
CustNo,
CustName
From Customer)
;
Alter Table qtemp.cust
add Column Revenue
;
Update Table qtemp.cust A
Set Revenue = (select sum(revenue) from Sales B Where A.CustNo = B.CustNo)
;
Insert into F_SALES
Select * from qtemp.cust
```

It's not that they have been idiots,  so the above statement where all info are in the sales table they would just group by and take the info from there.  But in general all code are build like above.  and often there are used qtemp tables instead of subqueries or CTE..  And in lack of a better word i call the old work   Stepped process and my own work for one step process.

So are there are termonology for it?

Also its on and old DB2 server, which are now the newest db2 version.. but is it legacy from a time where db2 didn't support  DT, CTE, subqueries etc.     I'm very currious why anyone would build it like above, and if there is a name for it?

Comment: This code seems to be some kind of "modernization" of and old process from the 80s/90s (not just before CTE, but before SQL was a common tool). Someone has used SQL but was still thinking the old way. CTEs have been there since at least V5.4 (2006), V7.5 has been announced last month

Comment: That "old way" could be useful to peek at intermediate results. This could be of critical value for specific applications like banking or accounting (computing balance, assets, etc.), so it may be the case that previous developers wanted to see the result of after step #N, to veriy all is good.